# Android LinearyLayout with TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a `LisView` item that contains a `LinearLayout` with two `TextView` objects. The first object needs to be 70% of the screen width, and the other needs to be fixed at a 125dp width.

I am using the `layout_weight` attribute to tell the layout to make the first `TextView` scale appropriately, but I'm not able to get it working correctly. It looks fine in the preview box (Screenshot 1), but in the emulator the `TextView` on the left is always resized to just fit it's contents (Screenshot 2).

Does anyone know what's going on? I'm new to Android development, so this is just baffling me.

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValueTextView"
        android:layout_below="@id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="20,000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Design Preview Screenshot 1]

[image: Emulator Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When providing a weight, width (or height for vertical layouts) has to be 0dp.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:weightSum="10"
              android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ValueTextView"
        android:layout_below="@id/TitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="20,000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that and had the same issue. I've copied your exact layout XML into my project, and I still get the same result. Everything I've read is in-line with what you mentioned, but this just doesn't work for me. Could it be a default parameter of the text view is causing this behavior? I tried searching but cannot find anything on it.

Comment: @miken.mkndev did you also set the weightSum on the LinearLayout?

Comment: It is simply auto-resizing the textview to match it's contents and not respecting the linear layout. I also have no code that modifies these elements. It's all handled in the XML

Comment: One interesting thing I found is I changed the views from a TextView to a normal View and the layout works. However, it's backwards. The view that should be 70% is 30% and vice versa. Would this be caused by gravity?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured out the issue. Two things were incorrect. First, the answer from @user3249477 is correct that I needed to include the weightSum in the parent LinearLayout tag, and I also needed to set the width to 0dp for the text elements that should scale.

However, this still did not actually fix my problem. The actual problem was the parent ListView had it's width and height set to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent". I updated this and the layout started to work.

I will am accepting the answer from @user3249477 as he was correct but I also would appreciate it if anyone could up-vote this answer as it did allow the fix above to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent`.

Comment: Also avoid using `wrap_content`, when you can. It will speed up the measuring process.